# Como voltar de um fragment para uma activity?

Tags: java, android

Eu criei uma Activity do tipo Drawer Navigation e nos ícones dessa Activity tem uma ação que me levam para um fragmento.

Meu problema é que eu não sei voltar de um fragmento para uma activity ...
como eu devo fazer para voltar com o botão voltar do onBackPressed?

Tentei simular o botão de voltar com isso mas não funcionou aqui:

```
Start fragment:

  public void showMyFragment(View V){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new MyFragment();

        if (fragment != null) {
             FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
             fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
        }   
}





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        this.finish();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}



public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_info, null);
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é usar o [**`addToBackStack()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)). Veja como deve ser:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment)
    .addToBackStack("Fragment").commit();
```

Sendo assim, você pode colocar uma condição verificando se a cotagem de entrada de *stack* tem valor maior que `0`. Se sim, use o método `popBackStack()`, que fará o usuário voltar para o *fragment* anterior, senão ele usa o `super.onBackPressed()`. Veja:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

#### Um GIF vale mais que mil imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este projeto está salvo como [navDrawer](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/navDrawer) no GitHub.

Comment: Consegui!!!Lindo!Show!

Answer (score 3):

Ao usar `addToBackStack(null)` está a incluir os fragments na navegação, fazendo com que o "Botão Voltar" apresente o *fragment* anterior.

Se não quer navegar para trás entre os *fragments* abertos não adicione a *transanction* ao *backstack*. Não use `addToBackStack(null)`.

Altere

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
               .addToBackStack(null)
               .commit();
```

para

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
               .commit();
```

No entanto, se quiser manter a navegação entre *fragments* e, ao mesmo tempo, dar a possibilidade de retornar à Activity anterior, tem de implementar o "Botão Para Cima".

Siga os seguintes passos:

- Declare qual é a Activity pai de cada Activity. Isso é feito no AndroidManifist.xml usando o atributo `android:parentActivityName`:

  ```
  <application ... >
      ...

      <!-- A main/home activity (não tem uma activity pai) -->

      <activity
          android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
          ...
      </activity>

      <!-- Uma activity filha da main activity -->
      <activity
          android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MyChildActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_child"
          android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

          <!-- meta-data para suportar Android 4.0 ou inferior -->
          <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
              android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
      </activity>
  </application>
  ```
- Torne o "Botão Para Cima" disponível/visível

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  }
  ```
- Use o método estático `navigateUpFromSameTask()`, de NavUtils, para navegar para a Activity pai:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
      case android.R.id.home:
          NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
          return true;
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  ```

Para mais informações veja [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html), na documentação.

Outros tópicos para ler:

- [Navigation with Back and Up](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).
- [Implementing Effective Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html).

Comment: Gostei da resposta...amanhã irei implementá-la amigo =D e te dou um retorno....

Comment: Aliás fazer isso agora. =D

Comment: Não deu certo =[

Comment: O que não deu certo? Devo ter entendido mal a sua pergunta, porque aquilo que a resposta que você aceitou sugere é o que você já fazia(usar `addToBackStack(null)`) o que obriga a navegar para trás por todos os *fragments* antes de voltar à Activity.

Comment: Seria bom se tivesse uma forma de navegar programado. tipo não voltar de um em um...

Comment: Não entendo. O que é proposto na resposta aceite é o que você diz não querer: voltar um a um. Devemos sempre seguir o que é aconselhado pela google para que a experiência do usuário seja sempre a mesma, qualquer que seja a aplicação que esteja a utilizar. Em termos de navegação é [aconselhado](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html) que o "botão voltar" sirva para percorrer o backstack e o "botão para cima" percorrer para níveis superiores(Activities). É o que eu tentei explicar na minha resposta.

Comment: Ahhh entendi...